# Divide five bullets in each slide using C#

Tags: c#

I want to count bullets in each slide, if slide contains more than four bullets then then remaining bullets are shifted into newly created slide but if remaining bullets are greater than four then put four into one slide and reaming are shifted onto another slide.  This code counts the number of bullets in each slide if slide contains more than five bullets then it shift bullets into newly created slide. but this is not properly working . help to solve this .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;

namespace PPTBullets
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application app = new Application();
            app.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
            Presentation pres = app.Presentations.Open(@"C:\test.pptx");
           Application app = new Application();
            app.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
            Presentation pres = app.Presentations.Open(fileName);
            int toAdd = 1;
            for (int slideCount = 1; slideCount <= pres.Slides.Count; slideCount++)
            {
                Slide slide = pres.Slides[slideCount];
                foreach (object item in pres.Slides[slideCount].Shapes) //get all objects in all slides
                {
                int bulletCount = 0;
                int paragraphCount=0;

                    var shape = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape)item;
                    if (shape.HasTextFrame == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                    {
                        if (shape.HasTextFrame == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                        {
                            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.TextFrame2 textFrame = shape.TextFrame2;
                            TextRange2 textRange = textFrame.TextRange;
                            TextRange2 ps = textRange.Paragraphs;
                            paragraphCount = ps.Count;
                            for (int i = 1; i <= paragraphCount; i++)
                            {
                                BulletFormat2 bulletFormat2 = ps.Item(i).ParagraphFormat.Bullet;
                                if (bulletFormat2.Type != MsoBulletType.msoBulletNone)
                                {
                                    //this paragraph has has bullet
                                    bulletCount++;
                                }
                            }
                            if (bulletCount > 4)
                            {        

                                //create new slide, cut this paragraph and paste in the new slide
                                Slide tempSlide = pres.Slides.AddSlide(2, pres.Slides[1].CustomLayout);
                                ps.Item(slideCount).Cut();
                               tempSlide.Shapes[2].TextFrame.TextRange.Paste();

                            }

                        }
                    }
                 }
            }
             pres.Save();
              pres.Close();
                app.Quit();
        }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Your bullet count was not in the right place.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var app = new Application { Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue };
        Presentation pres = app.Presentations.Open(@"C:\test.pptx");
        for (int slideCount = 1; slideCount <= pres.Slides.Count; slideCount++)
        { 
            int bulletCount = 0;
            foreach (object item in pres.Slides[slideCount].Shapes) //get all objects in all slides
            {
                var shape = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape)item;
                if (shape.HasTextFrame == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                {
                    var paragraphs = shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= paragraphs.Count; i++)
                    {
                        BulletFormat2 bulletFormat2 = paragraphs.Item(i).ParagraphFormat.Bullet;
                        if (bulletFormat2.Type != MsoBulletType.msoBulletNone)
                        {
                            //this paragraph has has bullet
                            bulletCount++;
                        }
                    }

                    if (bulletCount > 4)
                    {
                        //create new slide, cut this paragraph and paste in the new slide
                        Slide tempSlide = pres.Slides.AddSlide(2, pres.Slides[1].CustomLayout);
                        paragraphs.Item(slideCount).Cut();
                        tempSlide.Shapes[2].TextFrame.TextRange.Paste(); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        pres.Save();
        pres.Close();
        app.Quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public void DivideBullets(Presentation presentation, int slideIndex)
        {

```
        var list = new ArrayList();
        new ArrayList();
        int toadd = 1;
        var newlst = new ArrayList();
        var str = new string[4];
        string strHeader = "";
        ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();
        int shapeCount = 0;
        foreach (object item in presentation.Slides[slideIndex].Shapes) //get all objects in all slides
            {
            int bulletCount = 0;
            int paragraphCount=0;
                var shape = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape)item;
                if (shape.HasTextFrame == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                {
                    if (shape.HasTextFrame == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                    {
                        shapeCount +=1;
                        if (shapeCount == 1)
                        {
                            strHeader = shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
                        }
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.TextFrame2 textFrame = shape.TextFrame2;
                        TextRange2 textRange = textFrame.TextRange;
                        TextRange2 ps = textRange.Paragraphs;
                        paragraphCount = ps.Count;

                        for (int bullet = 1; bullet <= paragraphCount; bullet++)
                        {
                            BulletFormat2 bulletFormat2 = ps.Item(bullet).ParagraphFormat.Bullet;
                            if (bulletFormat2.Type != MsoBulletType.msoBulletNone)
                            {
                                //this paragraph has has bullet
                                bulletCount++;
                                //MessageBox.Show( ps.Item(i).Text);
                                if (bulletCount > 4)
                                {
                                    //create new slide, cut this paragraph and paste in the new slide
                                    list.Add(ps.Item(bullet).Text);
                                }
                                newlst.Add(ps.Item(bullet).Text);
                                lst.Add(ps.Item(bullet).Text);
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }

            }
            int slideCounter = 0;
            if (newlst.Count <= 4)
            {
                newlst.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
               // strHeader = newlst[0].ToString();
                newlst.CopyTo(0, str, 0, 4);
                AddNewPptSlide(presentation, slideIndex + toadd, str, strHeader,0,_standard); // adding new slide
                toadd += 1;
                str[0] = "";
                str[1] = "";
                str[2] = "";
                str[3] = "";
                slideCounter = slideCounter + 1;

            }
            if (list.Count > 0)
            {
                int xx = 0;

                for (int x = 0; xx < list.Count; x++)
                {
                    str[x] = list[xx].ToString();
                    if (x == 3)
                    {
                        AddNewPptSlide(presentation, slideIndex + toadd, str, strHeader, 1, _standard); // adding new slide
                        toadd += 1;

                        slideCounter = slideCounter + 1;
                        str[0] = "";
                        str[1] = "";
                        str[2] = "";
                        str[3] = "";
                        x = -1;
                    }
                    xx++;

                } //End for (int x = 0; xx < list.Count; x++)
                if (list.Count % 4 != 0)
                {
                    AddNewPptSlide(presentation, slideIndex + toadd, str, strHeader, 1, _standard); // adding new slide
                    toadd += 1;
                } // if (list.Count%4!= 0)

            } //if(list.Count>0)
            newlst.Clear();
            list.Clear(); //clear ArrayList
            strHeader = "";
            if (lst.Count > 4)
            {
                presentation.Slides[slideIndex].Delete();
            }
        }
```